# GitHub Desktop Not Detecting Changes in Repo

Tags: git, github, synchronization, github-desktop

I have been working on a repo for some time, and I have been pushing code to it from a total of 2 machines (my desktop PC and my laptop). Whenever I change something from my PC and I need to push it, GitHub works normally and detects all the code I have added locally. So I commit, sync and it gets uploaded into the online repo.

My problem comes when I then try to sync my other machine(laptop), which doesn't have the newest commits I made from my pc. GitHub does not detect them and says my laptop repo is up-to-date when in fact it isn't. If I delete my local repo and create it again (empty) then GitHub detects it correctly.

I imagine I am doing something wrong, cause this seems to big of an issue to be just a bug, so I was wondering if anyone could point out to me what am I missing.

*For additional information this is what my process looks like: 
I write come code, open GitHub app give some description about the changes then I click "Commit" and then sync. I only work on 1 master branch.

Answer (score 1):

> My problem comes when I then try to sync my other machine(laptop), which doesn't have the newest commits I made from my pc

The solution here is to just do a `git pull` on the branch in question.  I've never used GitHub's desktop app, but pulling is so basic that it can't possibly be difficult to do this.

> GitHub does not detect them and says my laptop repo is up-to-date when in fact it isn't.

Here's the thing: Your local Git only "knows" whatever the *local* tracking branches tell it.  So, if your were working on `master` then GitHub desktop would be using `origin/master` as a reference for what the state of this branch actually is in GitHub.  Of course, as you pointed out, your local branch is not up to date.  Doing either a `git fetch` or doing a `git pull` would remedy this, as it would bring the local tracking branch up to date.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I am aware I can get the job using the command line, I wast just wondering how I could get the UI thing working. Anyways, if I don't find a solution I will get back to the good old git bash.

Comment: I'm not a GitHub desktop expert, but I think your problem basically sums up to having to do a pull.

Comment: Hmm, I just checked with git log, and it turns out even git log does not list the latest changes I made from my laptop. I'm guessing I am doing something wrong then. :(

Comment: Yes, it sounds like it, make sure you are in the right location when you type `git log`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by switching to another Repository in Github Desktop and then switching back.